# Run the view but don't call the methods in the controllers .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I had a routing problem in ASP.NET; I typed the controllers and it didn't access the views, so I went to STARTUP.CS and changed the `endpoints.MapRazorPages()` and put

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints = >
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Customers}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
 });
```

but now it doesn't access the controller's methods, it doesn't send the data to the controller it can process.

My startup.cs

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddDbContext<KonsiContexto>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Padrao")));
  
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();


    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
      

        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Clientes}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide full STARTUP.CS file, please? See also: https://www.infoworld.com/article/3541611/how-to-use-endpoint-routing-in-aspnet-core-30-mvc.html

Comment: Do you have Clientes Controller and Index action?